# Hyperlinks are not opening from Microsoft Excel (PHPExcel)

Tags: php, linux, phpexcel

I am using the following code to generate hyperlinks in excel

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column_index . $row_index)->getHyperlink()->setUrl( 'http://www.c4online.me/c4v2/index.php?q=file');
```

The link opens when the file is opened using "LibreOffice Calc" on ubuntu and using "Numbers" on Mac. But when it comes to Microsoft Excel 2007 and 2010 I get the following warning:

```
The internet site reports that the item you requested could not be found ( HTTp/1.0 404)
```

Can you please tell me when did I go wrong?

Comment: That URL gives me a 404 response when I try to access it from a web browser: I'm guessing that this is a custom 404 page that you're accessing and both Calc and Numbers ignore the 404 response and render the page regardless, but that MS Excel is more finickety.

Comment: i even tried to "www.msn.com" and i didn't work